# How to assign custom names to release artifacts on GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm evaluating GitHub as a way to keep under version control and share some excel files containing basically financial models.

The issue I'm facing is this one: I need to share the Release artifacts (a bunch of xlsx files) with people outside GitHub, so I'd like to include the version number in the filename to be sure that, even when the files will be further shared by business people through email or other non-GitHub means, that information won't be lost.

Is there a way to rename the artifacts automatically? *GitHub Actions* seemed to be the right way to address this thing, but unfortunately they're still unavailable on the Enterprise Server my company is using (v 2.19.13, I don't have any administrative access to it, btw), and adding some CI toolchain just to rename some files is probably too much.

Thank you in advance for any response!
Michele

Comment: So are you looking for a way to rename release artifacts or how to attach the artifacts to a release? Also are the excel files in your repository, or are they coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Excel files are managed within the repo. Think of them as my source code. To me would be the same to: A) rename the release artifacts or B) add a 'versioned' artifacts to the ones created by GitHub. The key is that this thing should happen automatically when I create a new release